# Some outbound calls are recorded others are not on Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, adhearsion

I am using FreePBX with Asterisk (1.8.15-cert1) and I am making calls through Adhearsion application. Now the scenario is that recording files are generated for every call, but only some contain actual recording others are empty having size 44 bytes.

I observed that calls made to regular phones are getting recorded while calls which are answered by an automated machine i.e. answering machine are not recorded (empty recording file is saved).

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have codec translation path from your call to .wav files(usualy mean check g729 codec present)

Comment: output of `core show translation recalc 10` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5371234

Comment: sorry,no other ideas. Can suggest turn on debug mode and see log.